# What is "prototype" in Number.prototype.toFixed()?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am trying to learn JavaScript. In order to use some methods of the Number object on the [Developer Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed), it is necessary to write a .prototype. What does prototype here mean and why should it be used? Can you give a proper explanation for someone new to the programing language?

[image]

Comment: _"In order to use some methods of the Number object [...] it is necessary to write a .prototype."_ - no, it is not. _"What does prototype here mean"_ - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes

Comment: This article might give you some insights about prototyping -> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/prototype-in-javascript/

Answer (score 2):

Some commenters directed you to resources with more information about prototypes in JavaScript, and there is also more information about the topic on the answers for [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work).

However, let's try to give a simple answer to the question at hand.

It should be noted that while the prototype methods are very common to use, you rarely explicitly type something like `Number.prototype`.

On JavaScript, each object (including objects that represent primitive values like numbers) has a *prototype object* from which it inherits properties and methods. The prototype is almost always an actual object though it may also be `Null`.

Number values, like `0` or `235.5`, have the `Number` object as their prototype.
Now, it may be a bit confusing, but `Number.prototype` does not refer to the prototype of the `Number` object. Instead, it is what the `Number` object *provides* when used as a prototype, to it's instance objects. So if, for example, you write `(23).toLocaleString()`<sup>1</sup>, then you are calling the method `toLocaleString` of the object `23`, which inherits it from the `Number` object.

<sub>**1:** The reason we have to add parentheses around `23` is because the `.` would otherwise be interpreted as decimal point, resulting in a syntax error. Another option would be to write `23..toLocaleString()` where the first dot would be a trailing decimal point (`23.` is a valid way to write 23 in JavaScript) and the *second* dot would be used for the property access.</sub>